# Where are these CSS files coming from?

Tags: html, css

So I am using YSlow and PageSpeed to try to speed up my pages a bit...

A few things I can not figure out is where are these additional stylesheets coming from, and why it says I have my google analytics tracking script in the `<head>` when I clearly do not.

YSlow, says I have these additional style sheets on my site:

```
css 22.2K   5.0K                http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/ya/r/Jiv2ScgfFwE.css 2012/9/4    621     
css 7.6K    2.0K                http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yK/r/eiDkkYU8S2N.css 2012/9/4    614     
css 20.6K   3.5K                http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/ya/r/Uv6EedIDPCH.css 2012/9/5    624     
css 13.1K   2.5K                http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/y-/r/ioAu8seq_Ap.css 2012/9/4    628     
css 17.1K   3.8K                http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/y2/r/YUXo2SiTAA4.css 2012/9/4    631     
css 40.2K   8.0K                http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/ya/r/I936Mc1COi1.css 2012/9/5    639     
css 3.9K    1.2K                http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yG/r/PNC3qf6bdQB.css 2012/9/4    635
```

And I have no idea where they are coming from.

I am using a template from the HTML5 BoilerPlate site...if that make any difference.

Then YSlow says, i have this analytics script in my `<head>`:

```
<script src="//www.google-analytics.com/ga.js">
```

but I have clearly looked into my page, and can see it is at the bottom of the page...

Sorry this sounds so dumb, but it just doesnt make sense...

the page is located here: http://jiujitsuboise.com/2012-Redesign/

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fbcdn.net` is Facebook's CDN. I guess you have a Facebook "Like" button or some other social plugin on the page.

(Edit: Yup, the "Find us on Facebook" box is the culprit.)

Comment: What about the Analytics script showing up in the <head> ... that one still boggles me...

Comment: @tony I don't know about that one. I could be that some script writes it into the `head` but then yslow shouldn't be complaining.  Very strange.